# What is this? The bottom half is loose can I still drive car

Tags: suspension

What is this part of my car near the wheel the bottom half came loose yesterday and making rattlerling noises how much will it cost to get fixed ? Can I still drive the car?

[image: ed]

Comment: Not the easiest to tell from the pic but that looks like the shock absorber to me - if that's the case I definitely wouldn't be driving anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure that is what came loose? More pictures and a bit of background would help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I think we need more pictures to see what exactly is loose - if it's the shock itself then that's very bad, but I think you'd notice much more serious symptoms, so I'm wondering if it's just a mud shield or similar around the shock that's loose

Comment: Other than a shock , it could be power steering. The degree of problem depends on what "loose" means.

Comment: Just looks like a *sleeve* which has slipped out of place. My Skoda did this and the mechanic gave it the "MOT" roadworthiness certicificate.

Comment: Hi thanks so taken it too a garage and it's just the dust cover tube has slid down they said for a quick temporary fix then just super glue it, iv done so and the rattle has now stopped so for now ilnsee how I get on thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the shock tube has come apart...time for new (do both sides).  You can drive it like this, but it can be dangerous at highway speeds. Without a damper, the tire will spend as much time off the ground as on.

This type of shock is relatively inexpensive...a few hundred dollars for both sides-installed, any shop can do them.  If this is a vehicle that doesn't get much use, (low speed, city driving and not interested in spending a lot) then sure, just change what's broken.

The shock absorbers are not just about smoothing the bumps you feel, they keep the tires on the road...

Comment: if it's just an outer plastic sleeve it's not so serious though.

Comment: Hi thanks so taken it too a garage and it's just the dust cover tube has slid down they said for a quick temporary fix then just super glue it, iv done so and the rattle has now stopped so for now ilnsee how I get on thanks for your help